# Are two FPLLs in sync?

Tags: digital-logic, pll

Two FPLLs are being driven by a common clock and the output of each FPLL is used to drive a counter after achieving a lock. When we turn on the circuit both FPLLs miraculously lock EXACTLY at the same time. We leave the hardware running and return after 10 years. Questions:
1.Will both counters show the same value?
2.If not, would the result be different if we used an integer PLL instead of an FPLL?

[image]

Comment: What's the probability of a power outage in ten years? How reliable are your components?

Answer (score 1):

> Two FPLLs are being driven by a common clock and the output of each FPLL is used to drive a counter after achieving a lock. When we turn on the circuit both FPLLs miraculously lock EXACTLY at the same time.

This is sort of hinting that they lock with the same phase. However, locking at the same time does not guarrantee that, as they have an internal state that affects the phase. If part of the start up is a sync pulse given to both PLLs to reset all of the internal state, respecting proper setup and hold times to the incoming reference, then you could have the same phase output.

> We leave the hardware running and return after 10 years. Questions:
> 1.Will both counters show the same value?

If the phase of the signals is different, then the counters will sometimes show the same count, and sometimes one will be ahead by one count.

Even if the phase has been sync'd up to be nominally the same, phase noise between the channels will mean that one or the other counter would flip first, and so if observed at the nominal clock edge, they may read differently. If observed away from the clock edge then yes, they would show the same value.

> 2.If not, would the result be different if we used an integer PLL instead of an FPLL?

The phasing of an integer PLL locked with a reference of 600 Hz (necessary to get 132.4242 MHz output from 120 MHz reference, it's their HCF) has exactly the same issues as a fractional PLL that can produce exactly the same frequencies.

If they both continue operating in their proper operating area for the 10 years, then their phase at the end will be the same as at the beginning. However, there are things that could cause an upset in one channel that doesn't affect the other one. A drop in power supply voltage may cause one channel to mis-count when the other doesn't, or a cosmic ray hit may cause a change of state. Those are external events, but there could be a simple failure of one side.

Comment: Won't there be a drift between the values of the counters caused by differences 
in division accuracy tolerance between both PLLs ?

Comment: @shaiko I was kind of assuming that they were identical FPLLs, and being digital, both are exact. I'm not so paranoid to make the worst assumption there. If you assume inexact PLLs - possible to build, but why, then you would have differences in division accuracy.

Comment: The real world scenario I'm facing is that the counters exist inside 2 FPGAs and the FPLLs are also inside those FPGAs. So, I have no way of telling whether the FPLLs are the same or not.

Comment: @shaiko generally if the modulus of each FPLL is the same, then they are going to run the same with the same numerator. The modulus gives you the translation to the equivalent integer PLL with a much lower reference frequency. But, if you are trying to guess behaviour for hidden IP, then you might be in trouble.